# Почему при событии onclick, не происходит вызов функции?

Tags: javascript, pure_js

```
function $(selector)
{
  var prefix = selector[0];
  selector = selector.substring(1);
  switch(prefix){
    case '#': return document.getElementById(selector);
    case '.': return document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
    default: return document.getElementsByTagName(prefix + selector);
  }
}

$('.wrapper').onclick = function() {
  alert('Hello world!');
}
```

Comment: @lampa, будьте добры, подскажите еще пожалуйста, как выбрать за один раз несколько селекторов, как это реализовано в jQuery, например $('.wrap, #reg')? 

Буду очень Вам признателен.

Comment: @alex83 вам нужно будет разбить слово на несколько частей. И каждую часть отдельно обработать.

Comment: @lampa, а можно чуть подробнее, что-то я не совсем понял... Точнее, совсем не понял.

Comment: >var selectors = selector.split(','); 

Дальше массив разбираете. Вы взялись за задачу, но почему-то в поиск категорически не хотите залазить. Не правильно подходите к решению задачи.

Comment: @lampa, спасибо. Приму к сведению все выше сказанное.

Comment: @alex83 жду от вас положительных результатов :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов функции обернули в `dom ready`? Или у вас код стоит после контента?

Что говорит дебаггер?

Смотрите, в чем тут дело-то! Метод  `getElementById(selector)` возвращает ссылку на узел объекта, когда `getElementsByClassName(selector)` и `getElementsByTagName(prefix + selector)` возвращают не объект, а массив объектов. Даже если на странице только один элемент.

Дальше сами разберетесь? Я в вас верю всей своей душой!

Comment: ах да, как я мог это пропустить. Обновил пост.

Comment: @lampa,

На сколько я понял, если возвращается массив объектов, то в данном случае js не выбирает ничего. Но тогда как указать, что нужно выбрать именно тот элемент, которому было адресовано событие. В jQuery, в таких ситуациях применяется this, а как это осуществить на чистом JS???

У меня правильный ход мыслей, или...?

Comment: @Alex83 ну вы же понимаете, что на странице объектов с классом `.wrapper` может быть сколь угодно! В данном случае вам нужно просто пройтись по массиву и поставить всем объектам массива нужное событие.

Comment: @lampa, вот http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/kzWQE/

Comment: @alex83 у вас в jsfiddle 2 раза функция window.onload вызывается, по этому и не работает. http://jsfiddle.net/kzWQE/1/

Comment: @lampa, спасибо, что вытерпели...

Удачи

Comment: @alex83 Всегда пожалуйста :-)

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` возвращает массив элементов, и вы этому массиву задаете событие `onclick`. Заметьте, массиву, а не элементам. Поэтому надо пройтись по элементам и каждому задать событие `onclick`. А функции желательно дать название и привязывать по названию, чтобы не плодить кучу лишних функций.

Comment: Это я уже понял, вот только не знаю как прикрутить к этому цикл, чтобы он прошелся по всем элементам...

Comment: @Alex83 покажите, как вы пробовали пройтись циклом по массиву.

Comment: @lampa, посмотрите пожалуйста...    

    var x = $('.wrapper');

    for( i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
     x[i].onclick = function() {
       alert('Hello world!');
     }
    }

Comment: @Alex83 ну правильно по идее всё. Работает же?

Comment: @lampa, в том то и дело, что не работает...

Comment: @alex83 всё прекрасно работает. Я надеюсь вы не забыли данный код в dom ready обернуть?

Comment: @lampa, не забыл. Вот, взгляните http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/hQs9J/

Comment: @alex83 так а где ваша функциято?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы на вашем месте заменил вашу конструкцию этой

```
$$ = function(selector, context) {
    context = context || document;
    if (!selector.indexOf("#"))
        return context.querySelector(selector);
    else
        return context.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Comment: А чем Ваш вариант лучше?

@lampa, что скажете?

Comment: Ну хотя бы тем, что можно выбрать контекст поиска объекта. А ещё короче.

Comment: @ReklatsMasters, а можно конкретный пример использования...

Comment: var input = $$('#ololo-trigger');
    input.checked = !input.checked;

переключаем чекбокс

Comment: Ну с id понятно, а как быть с class'ом? Добавить else if()?

Comment: @Alex83, как сказали выше просто перебираем циклом все элементы:

    var input = $$('input');  // tag  
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length;++i)
        input[i].checked = !input[i].checked;

Comment: @ReklatsMasters пока не вижу смысла так мудрить. Пусть сначала @Alex83 свой код освоит, а потом на другие переходит.